# Koppa under ASL abstract-template

Tags: fonts, symbols

I will be submitting an abstract using the required abstract template of the Association of Symbolic Logic: http://aslonline.org/abstractresources.html

It turns out that there are errors when I e.g. want to include the [`teubner` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/teabner). This prevents me from accessing the archaic Greek Koppa which I have used in earlier publication on the topic.

[image]

Is there a way around to access this archaic letter?

Comment: All questions should include a small complete document i.e. a Minimal (non-)Working Example. This makes it much easier to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works.

```
%% FIRST RENAME THIS FILE <yoursurname>.tex.
%% BEFORE COMPLETING THIS TEMPLATE, SEE THE "READ ME" SECTION
%% BELOW FOR INSTRUCTIONS.
%% TO PROCESS THIS FILE YOU WILL NEED TO DOWNLOAD asl.cls from
%% http://aslonline.org/abstractresources.html.


\documentclass[bsl,meeting]{asl}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\AbstractsOn

\pagestyle{plain}

\def\urladdr#1{\endgraf\noindent{\it URL Address}: {\tt #1}.}


\newcommand{\NP}{}
%\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{teubner}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\textgreek{\Koppa} \verb|\Koppa|

\textgreek{\koppa} \verb|\koppa|

\textgreek{\coppa} \verb|\coppa| 

%% BEGIN INSERTING YOUR ABSTRACT DIRECTLY BELOW;
%% SEE INSTRUCTIONS (1), (2), (3), and (4) FOR PROPER FORMATS

%\NP
\absauth{FirstName1 LastName1, FirstName2 LastName2, and FirstName3 LastName3}
\meettitle{Title of abstract with initial capital letter only, except for
Proper Nouns}
\affil{Department, University, Street Address, Country}
\meetemail{First author's email}
%%% NOTE: email required for at least one author
\urladdr{OPTIONAL}
%

%% INSERT TEXT OF ABSTRACT DIRECTLY BELOW


\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{cite1}
{\scshape Author's Name},
{\itshape Title of article},
{\bfseries\itshape Journal name spelled out, no abbreviations},
vol.~XX (XXXX), no.~X, pp.~XXX--XXX.
\end{thebibliography}

\vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}
%% this space adjustment is usually necessary after a bibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

It works elsewhere too:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did, and I got an error. I just retried it and I get an error even if I don't move things around. I've also tried recopying the code, deleting all auxiliary files and recompiling. Still, I can't get it to compile without error. To be clear: I get the output you show, but it does not compile without errors. In particular, it complains that `\previouslanguage` is undefined because no language is defined at the beginning of the document, that `\previousencoding` is undefined etc. I've deleted my previous comment as the errors occur whether or not you move stuff around.

Comment: Do you really not get errors? I assume we have the same version of `asl.cls`. Different versions of `babel`? Or `teubner`? My `babel` is 3.9j. `teubner` is 2013/12/31 v.4.2.

Comment: @cfr I don't get errors. 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/3OiQL.png With babel `   babel.sty    2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package`  I have added the output in the answer.

Comment: Curious. `babel`, then? Something changed in 3.9?

Comment: @cfr In miktex this is the latest babel. I updated today (2hrs ago)

Comment: Sure. But the fact that TL has a later version could still explain why I get errors and you don't! In fact, there is a newer version on ctan than even mine (3.9k 2014-03-24). I wonder if that will make a further difference?

Comment: Thank you! This solution works for me. I will not investigate the other solution as I do not need to go deeper.

Comment: @user24406 Could you tell us which distribution of TeX you are using and, if relevant, which version? e.g. TeX Live 2012, TeX Live 2013, MiKTeX...

Comment: I use TeX-studio 2.3 and I believe it was set up with TeX Live 2012. But I am not sure how to verify this.

Comment: texlive-science 2012.20120611-2 it seems. Zorin does not update TeX Live automatically, so I have to update some now.

Answer (score 3):

Harish Kumar's solution fails with `babel` 3.9j which is what TeX Live currently seems to have. MiKTeX is apparently using an older version (3.8m) which does not produce errors. [At least, this is my current working hypothesis - that the difference in versions of `babel` explains why my addition to the preamble is necessary with current TeX Live but not MiKTeX.]

This solution works without altering the order in which elements of the abstract are typeset from that specified in the template:

```
\documentclass[bsl,meeting]{asl}
\usepackage[greek,british]{babel}
\usepackage{teubner}

\AbstractsOn

\pagestyle{plain}

\def\urladdr#1{\endgraf\noindent{\it URL Address}: {\tt #1}.}

\newcommand{\NP}{}

\makeatletter
  \edef\previouslanguage{\languagename}
  \edef\previousencoding{\f@encoding}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\NP
\absauth{My Name}
\meettitle{Abstract title}
\affil{My Institution}
\meetemail{me@my.inst.uni}

\textgreek{\koppa}

\end{document}
```

[image: koppa abstract]

Comment: My solution works, unlike you claim ;)

Comment: @HarishKumar See my comment on your answer. Your solution does not compile without error here.

Comment: It compiles for me with latest miktex without any errors.

Comment: @HarishKumar I'm using TeX Live which appears to have a later version of `babel` than MiKTeX. I guess what we don't know is whether these are the same errors referred to in the original question... (Or quite what is causing them.)