# Intersection (\cap) for ASL-abstract

Tags: fonts, symbols

For my submission of an abstract using the required abstract template of the Association of Symbolic Logic (http://aslonline.org/abstractresources.html) I do not get the intersection sign properly. Here is my minimal example, but the asl.cls-file provided by the link is needed for compilation:

```
\documentclass[bsl,meeting]{asl}

\usepackage [greek, english]{babel}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{textcomp}

%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}

\AbstractsOn

\pagestyle{plain}

\def\urladdr#1{\endgraf\noindent{\it URL Address}: {\tt #1}.}


\newcommand{\NP}{}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{teubner}





\begin{document}

$\cap$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be inside `$`s?

Comment: I tried that as well, of course. But I will edit that for clarity.

Comment: I get an error due to `teubner`, but the intersection symbol is there.

Comment: @egreg http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169667/39222. The OP has an outdated version of `babel`. If your `babel` is current, the preamble addition avoids the error. But that obviously raises the question of whether some other package causes the missing symbol in TL 2012 despite its working fine with TL 2013 (or whatever you are using).

Comment: @cfr It appears that `teubner` is not compatible with `amsart`, which `asl.cls` is based on.

Comment: @egreg Meaning my solution there will have other side-effects?

Comment: @cfr I don't know. Surely it should be solved by `teubner`

Comment: @egreg Agreed but I imagine the OP may not wish to wait for an update so was trying to find a workaround.

Comment: @egreg Also, the version of `teubner` in TL 2012 (which the OP is using) turns out to be incompatible with LaTeX - at least if you want to typeset mathematics! So the problems here seem to go somewhat deeper...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution, I think, is to update your TeX installation. However, as your [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169664/39222) shows, updating may not be without pitfalls of its own.

I think it might be worth asking yourself just how much you need `teubner`. If it is only for the odd character (e.g. `\koppa`), I would think about whether there might be other ways to access those characters.

The particular version of `teubner` which you are using essentially screws up typesetting the intersection symbol. I ran `diff -Naur` to compare the final version of `teubner` in TeX Live 2012 with the current 2013 version. Here is a small part of the output:

```
-\DeclareTextCommand{\cap}{\GRencoding@name}{\cap@}
-\DeclareTextCommand{\cap}{OT1}{\cap@}
-\DeclareTextCommand{\cap}{T1}{\cap@}
-
+\let\mcap\cap
+\DeclareTextCommand{\tcap}{\GRencoding@name}{\cap@}
+\DeclareTextCommand{\tcap}{OT1}{\cap@}
+\DeclareTextCommand{\tcap}{T1}{\cap@}
+\DeclareRobustCommand*\cap{\textormath{\tcap}{\mcap}}
```

So basically, it seems that `teubner` was overriding the definition of `\cap`. This is why you get a complaint about any attempt to use `$\cap$` that the command cannot be used in maths mode (?!). Running it outside maths mode works but does not produce the intersection symbol:

[image: teubner's \cap]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage [greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage{teubner}

\begin{document}

\cap

\end{document}
```

Note that this is solely a function of `teubner` and has nothing to do with any conflict with `asl`. `teubner` conflicts with the basic definitions of maths symbols set up by LaTeX.

You can work around this particular problem by saving the value of `\cap` before loading `\teubner` and then inserting the code from the updated version after `\teubner` is loaded:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage [greek, english]{babel}
\let\mcap\cap
\usepackage{teubner}

\makeatletter
  \DeclareTextCommand{\tcap}{\GRencoding@name}{\cap@}
  \DeclareTextCommand{\tcap}{OT1}{\cap@}
  \DeclareTextCommand{\tcap}{T1}{\cap@}
  \DeclareRobustCommand*\cap{\textormath{\tcap}{\mcap}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\cap$

\end{document}
```

[image: intersection despite teubner]

However, there are all kinds of other nasties lurking here which are likely to cause unexpected output in a range of cases. Working around them one by one is likely to be a frustrating exercise. Updating is a better option. Although the current version of `teubner` is not unproblematic, it does seem to resolve some of the basic issues affecting you here.

To get the latest version, install TeX Live 2013 and then update the installation to ensure you get the December release of `teubner`. You could try just downloading the updated `teubner` from ctan and using that with your current installation. However, that might cause issues of its own.

If you do update, you should bear in mind that you may need [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169667/39222) to your other question. Given egreg's comments here, this might have unforeseen side-effects but it does allow both the intersection symbol and `\koppa` to be typeset in the same document. As I say, if you can possibly dispense with `teubner`, that would surely be the cleanest solution.